# VSCode: getting which launch configuration was used to run a standalone script (i.e. JavaScript with Node.js)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, launch

Can a JavaScript script being debugged and/or run via VSCode using Node.js know which launch configuration was used to launch it?

Something like:

```
var myLaunchConfigName = somehow_get_my_config()
console.log( 'I was launched by ' + myLaunchConfigName )
```

I've searched but couldn't find a way.

Comment: add an environment variable in the launch config

Comment: This way?

"env": { "MY_LAUNCH": "name_of_config" }

Comment: yes, can you access this environment variable in the script

Answer (score 1):

Following rioV8 suggestion, here is the complete answer:

1. Install package "dotenv" locally:

   ```
   npm install dotenv
   ```
2. Where to set environment variable values. Some alternatives are:

- in VSCode launch configuration ( launch.json or settings.json) :

  ```
   {
       "name": "node launch $ file",
       "type": "node",
       "request": "launch",
       "program": "${file}",
       "env": {"LAUNCH_CONFIG": "node launch $ file"} //<--ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
   }
  ```
- and/or create a file named ".env" in project root directory and add values to it:

  ```
  FROM_FILE="value from file"
  ```

  That is the default location for .env but it can be placed somewhere else.
- and/or pass them in the command line to node, as shown later.

3. "require" the package dotenv. Some alternatives are:

- add the following line at the beginning of the script:

  ```
   require('dotenv').config()
  ```
- and/or we can require it in the command line using option "-r" :

  ```
   node -r dotenv/config  script.js
  ```
- .env can be located in another directory:

  ```
   node -r dotenv/config  script.js  dotenv_config_path=/custom-path-to-env/.env
  ```

4. Passing variables in the command line:

   ```
   CLINE="cline" node script.js

   CLINE="cline" node -r dotenv/config script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom-path-to-env/.env
   ```

5. Finally, inside the script we can read their values using process.env.VARIABLE_NAME, i.e. :

```
    var foo = process.env.LAUNCH_CONFIG
```

---

```
require('dotenv').config()

function notDefined(value) {
    return ((value === undefined) || (value === null))
}

function checkVars(varName, value) {
    if (varName === 'LAUNCH_CONFIG')
        console.log( notDefined(value) ?
            `I came from command line, or variable ${varName} is missing.` :
            `I came from VScode with configuration named '${value}'.` )
    else
        console.log( notDefined(value) ?
            `variable ${varName} is missing.` :
            `variable ${varName} = "${value}"` )
}

console.log('')
checkVars('LAUNCH_CONFIG', process.env.LAUNCH_CONFIG)
checkVars('FROM_FILE', process.env.FROM_FILE)
checkVars('CLINE', process.env.CLINE)
```

---

## Results:

## Launched from Visual Studio Code:

```
I came from VScode with configuration named 'node launch $ file'.
variable FROM_FILE is missing.
variable CLINE is missing.
```

## Variables from default .env file :

```
node envar.js

I came from command line, or variable LAUNCH_CONFIG is missing.
variable FROM_FILE = "from default .env"
variable CLINE is missing.
```

## Variables from command line and another file:

```
CLINE="cline" node -r dotenv/config envar.js dotenv_config_path=/C/DEVELOP/JS/another_file

I came from command line, or variable LAUNCH_CONFIG is missing.
variable FROM_FILE = "from another file"
variable CLINE = "cline"
```

## Variables from another directory :

```
node -r dotenv/config envar.js dotenv_config_path=/C/DEVELOP/JS/ANOTHER_DIR/.env

I came from command line, or variable LAUNCH_CONFIG is missing.
variable FROM_FILE = "from another directory"
variable CLINE is missing.
```