# Objects in global array are not being released (Garbage Collection)

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, global-variables

Question about garbage collection.

I have a program in javascript where I have a global variable initialized in Application.js `let g_objArr = []`. This `g_objArr` is used to load a customers profile details. This array contains a bunch of objects detailing a customer profile. (ex: `[ {name: {first:John}, {last:Doe}}, {Address: {street: {5th street}, apartment: null}.., {...}]`

I use this `g_objArr` in a variety of places. But at some point it gets reset and reloaded when another customer profile is chosen in a function `loadCustomerDetails()`. This function loads a new customer profile if a new customer is selected, or it does nothing and returns the current customer if the same customer is selected again. Basically, it will assign `g_objArr = //some new array thats loaded from an api call`.

The problem is my program is using too much memory. Each `g_objArr` is very large and it seems like when a new customer is loaded, the memory of the old customer still remains, so the memory keeps growing.

My initial solution is to set `g_objArr.length = 0` which seemed to work in clearing the array as well as destroying the references to objects within the array.

However, my teammate said that I should look to see where the dangling references to objects within the array are, and if those dangling references are removed, then the garbage collector should clear the array itself without me having to explicitly set the length = 0.

Theres a lot of places where the array is used so it will take time to comb through them. Upon initial inspection I didnt see anywhere that could hold on to dangling references (ex. theres some for loops that use it but I assume once the loop ends/function exits it shouldn't matter)

My question is, is my teammate correct? Or is the fact that `g_objArr` is a global mean that the references to objects within the array will never be cleared, unless explicitly done so (length = 0 approach).

Thanks so much!

Extra: the application is not hosted on the web, its on vscode. Not sure if theres a memory analysis tool there.

Comment: Why exactly is it an array? If there's only one object at a time, it does not seem to me that an array is necessary.

Comment: its an array because its a large codebase and when i touched it it was already a large array. There are discussions on turning it into a dictionary though. Would the garbage collection be any different if I refactor it into a dictionary?

Comment: Whether or not you first set `.length` to zero before assigning a new array, does not make any difference. In both scenarios you could still have references to the objects in that array, and setting `length` to 0 does not change that. Secondly, the garbage collector does not have to free non-referenced memory immediately.

Comment: I see, it seems to never free the old memory in the array though. I was wondering if the problem is that its a global variable. I'm not sure if objects within a global array will ever be freed

Comment: That doesn't matter. What matters is whether you have references to these objects. If that is not clear from your code, you should refactor your code. Well written code allows to easily ensure you don't have "dangling" references. Making such references with only local variables will help a lot to ensure that. Having lots of global variables makes that difficult.

Comment: How exactly are you measuring how much memory is being consumed? Often a garbage collector won't even bother to do anything if there's plenty of memory available. It definitely won't watch memory like a hawk and reclaim garbage as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**V8**

After a quick search it turns out that vscode is an electron app, which uses nodejs and the V8 JavaScript engine. If you wish to conduct your own search to confirm the result please do.

**GC**

Memory Garbage Collection in JavaScript is based on whether data stored on the heap can be reached by code, which is not *exactly* the same as holding references to the data on the heap. Global variables are most certainly "reachable" and will not be gc'd simply because *currently* there are no other references to it in code.

GC is also automatically conducted by the JS engine. It can be manually triggered in node by calling `global.gc`, but that needs to be exposed in node configuration using the `--expose-gc` flag. It [may be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69776006/5217142) to configure vscode at start up to launch node with additional configuration, but it is not something I can personally confirm.

**Dangling References**

Copying the value of `g_objArr` in parts of code has the potential to reduce the amount of available heap space:

```
const userData = g_objArr;
```

creates a reference to the array currently held in `g_objArr`. If `g_objArr` is updated, `userData` is now the no longer needed previous value. If it is still reachable (say if executed at file level in a module, or function level in a closure with nested functions that can be reached), it won't be gc'ed until the assignment to `userData` is executed again. If this is done in multiple places, in code that is *not* executed for every user, then it could very well impact available heap space.

Similar considerations apply to holding references to array entries, or the result of calling `Array` methods such as `slice` that create cloned copies of all or part of a single user's data.

If this is what your team mate intended as looking for dangling references then you should do so. You should do so anyway :-)

To repeat comment from @Pointy, proving you have a memory leak should take into account that the GC may be called quite intermittently by the JS engine. If the problem is that the size of the user's profile can grow beyond what can reliably be placed on the heap, with a logical upper limit of less than half the available heap size, then the problem is one of design rather than garbage collection.